# Ormlite left join query

Tags: java, ormlite

I have two tables:

`Transaction` with columns `id`, `description`, `value` and `card_id`

`Card` with columns `id` and `name`.

How to write following query with ormlite?

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction 
LEFT JOIN Card ON transaction.card_id = card.id 
WHERE transaction.value > 0 AND (transaction.description LIKE '%query%' OR card.name LIKE '%query%')
```

I can write

```
QueryBuilder<Transaction, Long> tranBuilder = transactionDao.queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<Card, Long> cardBuilder = cardDao.queryBuilder();
tranBuilder.leftJoin(cardBuilder);
```

But how to write WHERE condition using `where()` methods with correct AND, OR and parentheses?